# Add records to a google spreadsheet using google script without access to that sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a spreadsheet that works as a form and allows users to enter information in another sheet that acts as database. I have total 110 users and all of them will have a separate spreadsheet for entering data. They wont have access to the spreadsheet that acts as database. I have written script to cut data from their sheet to master sheet and it works when I do it because I have access to both of the sheets. But whey they run the script it gives access denied error.

Is there a way to run that particular script or all scripts as me master user so I can use my access rights?

Please advise. Help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: From what you said I gather that the best option would be to assign a view (read-only) permission to master user from 110 other accounts and run it from your account (not theirs) instead of assigning a edit (=write) permission for your 110 users to write to one db file.

Comment: I am owner of both and I can not give them any access to database file.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a webapp interface and publish it to run as you. Get each users spreadsheet from a config file, session.getActiveUser().getEmail tell you who is running it.
You will need to locks as well since users could run it simultaneously and all write to the same place.

Comment: Can you provide any resources that guide on how to make a webapp interface? I had tried that in past and failed as my knowledge of programming is very limited.

Comment: If you know html look at htmlService guides, else look at uiApp, many samples in the official gas docs.